# Windows 10 ADB driver to debug HTC phone via USB?

Tags: adb, windows, htc, usb-debugging, usb-drivers

I'm trying to test an application on an old HTC Incredible S smartphone (running Android 4.0.4). I've enabled USB debugging on the phone and connected the USB cable, but .\adb devices doesn't detect it.

I've successfully tested my app on an android tablet via USB, so I suppose the problem is with the ADB driver for my HTC device. I can transfer files to the HTC phone, but I can't use ADB to debug on it.

I'm using Android Studio with the SDK on Windows 10, with all current updates installed. I tried installing HTC Sync, but it didn't help. I've looked for the appropriate oem-usb driver at www.htc.com but couldn't find it.

I've found links to various "universal USB drivers" online, but don't know what's trustworthy and what's potential malware. Hoping someone more experienced can help!

Comment: Did you try this http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers ? For HTC, it says `Click on the support tab to select your products/device. Different regions will have different links.`

Comment: Google USB driver should work. But install the driver using device manager

Comment: I did follow the link to HTC from developer.android.com, but couldn't find a driver listed in my region (Australia, where I bought the phone). I'm curious if the drivers are available in other regions, though I doubt it. Or maybe it's been there all along, and I just don't see it? Don't know.

Comment: I also tried to install a Google USB driver (sdk\extras\google\usb_driver) using Device Manager, but it said "Windows was unable to install your USB Composite Device".

Comment: I'm looking into the Universal ADB Driver from Koush.com, which is available at [github](http://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver). It seems to work in Windows 10 at least for some people (though there might be open issues for others). But I'm concerned about installing unknown (to me) software on my WIndows machine that could also potentially root my phone too. Apologies to everyone for my mistrust, but I'm very new this community and don't yet know what's what here.